# Is it possible to install RPM build on Debian?

Tags: docker, build-pipeline

I have a Docker-based Debian Sid build environment for Go. The build script of an is configured to build both .deb and .rpm.

The rpm build process of a component I  wish to build requires though the tool `rpmbuild`.

Is it possible to install rpmbuild on Debian or should I better try another Linux distro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indeed build RPMs on Debian. You need the `rpm` and `rpmbuild8` packages:

I tried it with a docker container:

```
docker run --rm -it debian bash -c 'apt-get update && \
apt-get -y install rpm librpmbuild8 && which rpmbuild'
```

---

More info on packages:

```
The following additional packages will be installed:
  dbus debugedit libapparmor1 libarchive13 libdbus-1-3 libdw1 libexpat1 libgdbm-compat4 libgdbm6 libicu63 liblua5.2-0 libmagic-mgc libmagic1 libnspr4
  libnss3 libperl5.28 libpopt0 librpm8 librpmio8 librpmsign8 libsqlite3-0 libxml2 netbase perl perl-modules-5.28 rpm-common rpm2cpio
Suggested packages:
  default-dbus-session-bus | dbus-session-bus rpm-i18n lrzip gdbm-l10n file sensible-utils perl-doc libterm-readline-gnu-perl
  | libterm-readline-perl-perl make libb-debug-perl liblocale-codes-perl alien python elfutils rpmlint rpm2html
```